# Could not write JSON

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hello i am new to hibernate. I am working with JSON in spring. I want to show a user's details in JSON format but i got some error there. 
My error is:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.nishan.lifestyle.entity.User.pictureList, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.nishan.lifestyle.entity.User.pictureList, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-
>
> com.nishan.lifestyle.entity.User["pictureList"])
>   note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
>
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1

I have used following method to get all the user's details

```
public List<T> getAll() {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(persistClass);
    List<T> list = criteria.list(); 
    session.close();
    return list;
}

//getting JSON file

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/customer/customer-details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<User> getUserId() {
        return customerDaoImp.getAll();
    }
```

**User.java- Entity class**

```
        @Entity
    @Table(name = "tbl_user", catalog = "lifestyle", schema = "")
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userId = :userId")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByFullName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.fullName = :fullName")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByAddress", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.address = :address")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByContact", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.contact = :contact")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByGender", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.gender = :gender")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByDob", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.dob = :dob")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByActive", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.active = :active")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByCreatedDate", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.createdDate = :createdDate")})
    public class User implements Serializable {

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId")
        private List<Picture> pictureList;

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Integer userId;

        @Column(name = "full_name")
        private String fullName;

        @Column(name = "address")
        private String address;

        @Column(name = "contact")
        private String contact;

        @Column(name = "gender")
        private String gender;
        @Column(name = "dob")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date dob;
        // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation



        @Column(name = "email")
        private String email;



        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;


        @Column(name = "active", insertable = false)
        private short active;
        @Column(name = "created_date", insertable = false)
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date createdDate;

        public User() {
        }

        public User(Integer userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public User(Integer userId, String fullName, String email, String password, short active) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.active = active;
        }
//getter and setter
```

**Picture.java - Entity Class**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tbl_picture")
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Picture.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Picture p")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "Picture.findByPictureId", query = "SELECT p FROM Picture p WHERE p.pictureId = :pictureId")
        , @NamedQuery(name = "Picture.findByPictureName", query = "SELECT p FROM Picture p WHERE p.pictureName = :pictureName")})
    public class Picture implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

        @Column(name = "picture_id")
        private Integer pictureId;

        @Column(name = "picture_name")
        private String pictureName;
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        private User userId;

        public Picture() {
        }

        public Picture(Integer pictureId) {
            this.pictureId = pictureId;
        }

        public Picture(Integer pictureId, String pictureName) {
            this.pictureId = pictureId;
            this.pictureName = pictureName;
        }
//getter and setter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId")
    private List<Picture> pictureList;
```

to(workaround)

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId")
    private List<Picture> pictureList;
```

why workaround?

Remember that @OneToMany uses by default FetchType.LAZY that means collection are lazy-loaded by default but by changing to EAGER comes with another problem. All the collection will be loaded.

Hibernate Docs recommend to use by default LAZY, another way to fix this problem is to add HibernateModule and configurate to handle this scenarios.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate

Here is how to implement the module:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module = new Hibernate5Module();
    hibernate5Module.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
    hibernate5Module.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);

    objectMapper.registerModule(hibernate5Module);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY); //optional

    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    return messageConverter;
}
```

then in your class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

Comment: It only fetch the first row of the table multiple times

Comment: The problem with `Hibernate5Module` is that it's still broken and you can't lazily load entities. You have to walk through all your entities and their children that you want to print to make sure they're loaded before detaching them and/or passing them on to Jackson.